# Error en Sql-Server al ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

Tengo 3 parametros que recibe un procedure, ¿como se pasan los valores para las variables err_buff y ret_code ?, como nulas?, me marca el errores de numero invalido de parametros

```
PROCEDURE XX7E_EXT_FAC(err_buf OUT VARCHAR2,ret_code OUT NUMBER, P_TRX_NUM  VARCHAR2, P_CUST_NAME VARCHAR2, P_CUST_ID VARCHAR2);
```

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error `PLS-00306` es mostrado cuando intentas ejecutar un procedure y en la llamada no se especifica el número correcto de parámetros del procedure o los tipos de estos parámetros no son los mismos en la llamada al procedure que los de la creación.

Por el nombre de las variables que colocaste en la llamada al procedure es posible que hayas declarado la variable `P_TRX_NUM` como `NUMBER`.

Comment: el tipo es correcto, no se porque pasa :/

Comment: Puedes colocar el codigo de tu Procedure?